# I just installed GMP, where did it install to?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, configure

I just installed GMP with `./configure...make` and now I cannot seem to find where it installed to.

I checked in all the bins I could think of and nothing. It does import correctly when I write a C file and compile it though.

Where did GMP install to?

Comment: usually make will create some directory like `bin` or `build` where it will put the compiled binaries.

Comment: In case of `make install` the files by default should be in `/usr/local/bin` etc. But maybe reading [INSTALL.in](https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/master/INSTALL.in) will help OP to understand how installation works.

Comment: If you really wrote a code that uses gmp, then you can run "ldd /path/to/your/executable" and that will print which libraries it binds to and where they are. Another option is just to run "make install" again and either watch what's happening carefully or redirect the output of make and see there the target of install. Probably, it's /usr/local/lib.

Comment: @ClassStacker GMP is not GIMP and there is not much use in finding any executable.  See: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: @GombaiSándor Yes indeed. I misread that.

Answer (score 1):

Typing `./configure --help` shows a page with lots of useful info in which I can read that

```
By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.
```

So, unless you specified a different prefix than the default one, you should consider the options above.
Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Do configure --help and see what other options are available.
By standard, --prefix overrides all of them, so you need to override config location after specifying the prefix.

If you know the name of binary you can search it (e.g. bash):

```
find / -name "*bash*" -executable -type f  2>/dev/null
```

When you will find it you can add soft link or extend PATH to be able execute it like `gmp`